# xargs ignore blank line when using -d'\n'

Tags: xargs

I have a file input that may have blank lines, I want any empty lines skipped.
I am trying to find a solution that does not require using grep / tr and piping the output to xargs

I use the following xarg options

**-r** in the event of no arguments I do not want the command run.
**-d '\n'** new line is the delimiter.

command using echo:

```
echo "" | xargs -r -d'\n' -I {}  echo "test '{}'"
```

output:

```
test ''
```

command using file made of empty lines:

```
xargs -a /tmp/test.txt -r -d'\n' -I {}  echo "test '{}'"
```

output:

```
test ''
test ''
test ''
```

I could use grep as mentioned, but Id like to know if I can do it with just xargs.

grep example (working):

```
grep -v -e '^$' /tmp/test.txt | xargs -r -d'\n' -I {}  echo "test '{}'"
```

Comment: Try it without the `-0` option to `xargs`.

Comment: as mentioned the -0 option is required. some lines will have a single quote that cannot be escaped.

Comment: From the part of the man page that discusses the use of `-0`:   *When using this option you will need to ensure that the program which produces the input for xargs also uses a null character as a separator.*  Your `echo` and `grep` commands don't output a null character at the end of each line.  (a null character is a distinct character, not the same thing as an empty string or partial string)

Comment: as mentioned, the actual input is a file, the echo is serving as a test.

Comment: @SottoVoce you were correct I should not have been using -0. It conflicts with -n which also will not escape characters and was also overriding -0 anyway. Thanks for raising that.

Answer (score 8):

`-r` is not to ignore empty elements, it is to avoid running the command once if the input has no element (it's not needed with `-I` (nor BSD's `-J`) though).

You generally want `-r` for that reason.

```
find . -criteria -print0 | xargs -0 ls -ld
```

If `find` didn't find anything would still run `ls -d` without argument, and would list `.`.

So you do want:

```
find . -criteria -print0 | xargs -r0 ls -ld
```

For `ls` not to be run at all if `find` finds nothing.

Note that both `-r` and `-0` are GNU  extensions (same for `-d` which is even less portable). `-r` is the default behaviour in the `xargs` of some BSDs including FreeBSD's and NetBSD's (though that makes them non-POSIX compliant).

(in any case, no need for `xargs` in that particular example as you can do `find . -criteria -exec ls -ld {} +`).

As far as I know, GNU `xargs` is the only implementation that supports a `-d` option, and it has no support for filtering out specific argument values, be that empty ones or otherwise, so using `grep` (`grep -v '^$'` or `LC_ALL=C grep .`) is the way to go.

If you still wanted to use `-a` (another GNU extension), for instance so as to leave stdin untouched for the command, and with a shell with support for ksh-style process substitution (ksh, zsh, bash), you could do:

```
xargs -rd '\n' -a <(grep -v '^$' test.txt) cmd --
```

```
xargs -d '\n' -I{} -a <(grep -v '^$' test.txt) cmd -- {}
```

(the rc, akanga, es, fish and yash shells have equivalent features with different syntax).

Note that `-0` is like `-d '\0'`, so conflicts with `-d '\n'`. You have to choose which `d`elimiter you want. The latter will take precedence in `-0 -d '\n'` as it comes last.

`-0` is the preferred delimiter as that's the one byte value that cannot occur in a command's argument or a file's path. `-0`, contrary to `-d` is now found in many other `xargs` implementations (including those of most BSDs, Solaris, busybox, toybox, ast-open). With `xargs` implementations that don't support `-d` (that is, all but GNU `xargs`), you can use:

```
tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 ...
```

In place of GNU's:

```
xargs -d '\n' ...
```

If using `zsh`, instead of using `xargs`, you could do:

```
for arg ( ${(f)"$(<test.txt)"} ) cmd -- $arg
```

The `f` parameter expansion flag splits on newlines, and as `${...}` is left unquoted, empty elements are removed.

With `bash`:

```
readarray -t args < test.txt &&
  for arg in "${args[@]}"; do
    [ -z "$arg" ] || cmd -- "$arg"
  done
```

You could also do empty removal there by leaving the array expansion unquoted, but you'd also need to disable globbing and splitting which are also done upon unquoted parameter expansions:

```
IFS=; set -o noglob
readarray -t args < test.txt &&
  for arg in ${args[@]}; do
    cmd -- "$arg"
  done
```

You can also do things like:

```
while IFS= read <&3 -r arg || [ -n "$arg" ]; do
  [ -z "$arg" ] || cmd -- "$arg" 3<&-
done 3< test.txt
```

Which is standard `sh` syntax.

Comment: Im not using find.

Comment: @JacobJarick, I'm just mentioning `find` as an example for when you want `-r` (most of the times you want it).

Comment: thanks, so it does seem the only way is grep the file and pipe to xargs.

Comment: thanks I appreciate your clarification on the -r option. I interpreted it as a per argument input (eg some lines  being empty) not as a complete lack of inputs (no arguments at all).

Comment: @JacobJarick, see edit for further clarifications

Comment: re additional notes, 
I have tested with just -0 and just -d'\n' and -0 does not produce the preferred behaviour (which is 1 entry per command execution).

I also tried -0 with -n1 and -0 with -L1 but it did not behave as excepted.

-d'\n' alone does produce the desired results, characters such as single quote are not escaped.

Thanks for the additional clarification that -d and -0 are competing  arguments and the later one over rules the previous.

Comment: @JacobJarick, `-0` is to process NUL-delimited records as output by `find -print0` for instance. `printf 'a\nb\0c\0'` produces 2 of those records, the first one containing `a<newline>b` and the second containing `c`.

Answer (score 4):

> `-0` I don't want `'` and other characters escaped.
> `-r` I want blank lines ignored.
> `-d '\n'` new line is the delimiter.

The combination of `-0` and `-d '\n'` doesn't seem to make sense to me. `-0` tells `xargs` to use the NUL byte as a delimiter, while `-d '\n'` tells it to use a newline as the delimiter. Both disable quote and backslash processing.

> `-0`, `--null`
> Input  items  are  terminated by a null character instead of by whitespace, and the quotes and backslash are not special
> (every character is taken literally). [...]
>
> `--delimiter=delim`, `-d delim`
>
> Input items are terminated by the specified character. [...] **When processing the input, quotes and backslash are not special; every character in the
> input is taken literally.**  [...]

With the version of GNU find I have, the latter one seems to apply if both are given, compare e.g.:

```
$ printf 'foo\nbar\n' | xargs -0 -d'\n' -I {}  echo "<{}>"
<foo>
<bar>
$ printf 'foo\nbar\n' | xargs -d'\n' -0 -I {}  echo "<{}>"
<foo
bar
>
```

If you have an input with empty elements, and want to use `xargs`, I would just pipe through `grep .`, or `grep -z .` for NUL-separated values. (Or `grep -v '^$'`  if you need to accept lines that only contain byte sequences that *don't* form valid characters in the current locale.)

Filtering lines is what `grep` is for anyway, and since you're already forking off `xargs` as a separate process, adding the `grep` doesn't hurt much. Also it's easy to modify the regex to e.g. drop lines with only whitespace, if that's ever required.

Comment: I will edit my question as -0 and -d are conflicting options where the later takes precedence.
this was pointed out to me by Stéphane Chazelas

Comment: Beware `printf '\200\201\202\n' | grep .` for instance filters out that non-empty line in a locale using UTF-8 as charmap for instance. You'd need `LC_ALL=C grep .` for that to be equivalent to `grep -v '^$'`

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question to confirm you must use grep (or another tool) and pipe ouput to xargs to filter out blank inputs.

**Solution:**

```
grep -v '^$' /tmp/test.txt | xargs -r -d'\n' -I {}  echo "test '{}'"
```

As clarified by Stéphane Chazelas -r does not filter empty inputs but prevents running if there are no inputs.

from the xargs man page -r, --no-run-if-empty section:
*Normally, the command is run once even if there is no input.*

Additional note gained from further edits, -0 and -d are conflicting arguments with the later taking precedence.